# .htaccess help - from old domain and old subpages to new domain but old subpages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to rewrite htaccess to I get the following solution:

```
from www.mydomain.com**/pages/old** to www.examplenew.com**/pages/old**
or
from www.mydomain.com**/contactus** to www.examplenew.com**/contactus**
or 
www.mydomain.com**/attorneybio/myattorney** to www.examplenew.com**/attorneybio/myattorney**
or
www.mydomain.com**/practiceareas/DOM** to www.examplenew.com**/practiceareas/DOM**
```

Basically, what I need is: redirect old domain to a new domain but keep the same sub pages.  If someone types in the old domain from Yellow pages phone book they will be redirected to the new one.

Then, when they go to another page, let's say practice areas, they will be redirected with the new domain name in the address bar but with old subpage.   Please help.  I need to change my client's site by November 14th.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a DNS switchover from the old site to the new one?

Comment: Thanks, @paulsm4 but I don't think this is what I am looking for.  I am not changing the hosting providers - Godaddy.  My client wants to remove his bio and other information from the site because he is leaving the firm. The site needs to stay in tack, otherwise.  I have not designed this site I am taking it over. It is hard for me to understand how they coded this site, because there are two index pages, one in html one in php. Anyways, I am not very familiar with php.  My strong side is html, unfortunately.  They bought a new domain this weekend and I need to substitute the old name with new